# cannot show only date in the label asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

my label shows this

[image]

i don't know how to make it only view as a date without the time

because my database field is just date

[image]

CODES ASPNET:

```
<td> 
    <asp:Label ID="lbDeliveryDate" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" 
        Font-Size="Larger" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ></asp:Label>
</td>
```

CODE

```
void GetPO()
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT PO.POID, PO.RequestedByID, PO.ShippingMethod, PO.ShippingTerm, PO.Term, PO.DeliveryDate, Users.FirstName, Users.LastName FROM PO " +
            "INNER JOIN Users ON PO.RequestedByID=Users.UserID";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Session["userid"].ToString());
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        POID.Text = dr["POID"].ToString();
        lbFN.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
        lbLN.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
        lbUserID.Text = dr["RequestedByID"].ToString();
        lbShippingMethod.Text = dr["ShippingMethod"].ToString();
        lbShippingTerm.Text = dr["ShippingTerm"].ToString();
        lbPaymentTerm.Text = dr["Term"].ToString();
        lbDeliveryDate.Text = dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString();
        //Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString());
    }
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

Iam getting the data DATE from the other database which i have only saved as a date field

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your below line of code

```
lbDeliveryDate.Text = dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString();
```

with this

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString());
  lbDeliveryDate.Text =  String.format("{0}/{1}/{2}",dt.Month ,dt.Day, dt.Year );
```

Comment: @PaulineGailMallariChan Great ;)

Answer (score 2):

As I can see you have column type `Date` so it will already be in `DateTime` when you will receive it in C#. You just need to use `ToString()` to format it:

```
lbDeliveryDate.Text = dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString("d");
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**Your c# object is of Type DateTime**. That's the problem. May be you can convert the value to string and then assign it to the lable.

But later on you might need to convert it to DateTime again if you have to perform any manipulations. Depends on your scenario

**EDIT:** you can write a c# Extension to handle the conversion of dateTime to string. `Which you can reuse easily than writing up code everywhere in your application to handle Date convertion`

```
public static class StringFormatter
{
    public static string DateFormat(this string value)
    {
        if (value == "")
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            return DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can do this.

```
lbDeliveryDate.Text = dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString().DateFormat();
```

Comment: what? no the data comes from a data field which is date only

Comment: Or you can use javascript, or Jquery to manipulate the text as desired. This is another option.

Comment: i did `lbDeliveryDate.Text = string.Format(dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString());`
and `Convert.ToString.(dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString())`   still has the same values

Comment: So, the values from your database is coming that way. Now since you converted it to string you can rip the unwanted part by string split

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your time answering my question! i know this is just simple for you.

i just did as what @Arun Rana said

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString());
lbDeliveryDate.Text =  String.format("{0}/{1}/{2}",dt.Month ,dt.Day, dt.Year);
```

RATHER THAN:

```
lbDeliveryDate.Text = dr["DeliveryDate"].ToString();
```